# Sendgrid not sending email

Tags: python, sendgrid

I am using flask python to send emails using sendgrid, i followed the doc, where i install `pip install sendgrid` and did the following, but the email is not sent and responds with a status code of 202, is there something i am missing

```
import sendgrid
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Email, Content, Mail

def sendEmail():
        try:
            sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey="hiddedAPIKey")
            from_email = Email("test@example.com")
            to_email = Email("myemail@gmail.com")
            subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun"
            content = Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Python")
            mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
            response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
            print(response.status_code)
            print(response.body)
        except:
            print("the was an error")
```

Comment: Have u checked spam folder?

Comment: @skaul05 thanks, but how can it prevent it from going to spam folder

Answer (score 1):

Your emails must be going to **spam**. There are two ways to tackle this situation

- You can go into the spam folder and click on the from email address as the trusted email address. (Won't help for multiple sender addresses)
- Check the `sendgrid` official [documentation](http://d2w67tjf43xwdp.cloudfront.net/Classroom/Deliver/Undeliverable_Email/my_emails_are_going_to_spam.html) to avoid emails to land into spam.